# How to create a rotating rainbow color circle in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibezierpath, cgaffinetransform

From stackoverflow i got a code for drawing rainbow color circle.But as part of requirement ,I need that circle to be rotated continously ,like a rotating progress loader.Below is the code used for creating Rainbow color circle.

```
    class RainbowCircle: UIView {

    private var radius: CGFloat {
        return frame.width>frame.height ? frame.height/2 : frame.width/2
    }

    private var stroke: CGFloat = 10
    private var padding: CGFloat = 5

    //MARK: - Drawing
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        drawRainbowCircle(outerRadius: radius - padding, innerRadius: radius - stroke - padding, resolution: 1)
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, lineHeight: CGFloat) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        stroke = lineHeight
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder) }

    /*
     Resolution should be between 0.1 and 1
     */
    private func drawRainbowCircle(outerRadius: CGFloat, innerRadius: CGFloat, resolution: Float) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        context.saveGState()
        context.translateBy(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY) //Move context to center

        let subdivisions:CGFloat = CGFloat(resolution * 512) //Max subdivisions of 512

        let innerHeight = (CGFloat.pi*innerRadius)/subdivisions //height of the inner wall for each segment
        let outterHeight = (CGFloat.pi*outerRadius)/subdivisions

        let segment = UIBezierPath()
        segment.move(to: CGPoint(x: innerRadius, y: -innerHeight/2))
        segment.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: innerRadius, y: innerHeight/2))
        segment.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: outerRadius, y: outterHeight/2))
        segment.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: outerRadius, y: -outterHeight/2))
        segment.close()

        //Draw each segment and rotate around the center
        for i in 0 ..< Int(ceil(subdivisions)) {
            UIColor(hue: CGFloat(i)/subdivisions, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1).set()
            segment.fill()
            //let lineTailSpace = CGFloat.pi*2*outerRadius/subdivisions  //The amount of space between the tails of each segment
            let lineTailSpace = CGFloat.pi*2*outerRadius/subdivisions
            segment.lineWidth = lineTailSpace //allows for seemless scaling
            segment.stroke()

//            //Rotate to correct location
            let rotate = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat.pi*2/subdivisions)) //rotates each segment


            segment.apply(rotate)



        }
```

Please anyone help me in rotating this circle.

Please find below the circle generated with above code:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain bit more clear on `rotating the circle` ? Do you have any reference image or anything in precise ? It will help us for better understand

Comment: You need to animate UIBezierpath to show the progress, go trough - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847408/animate-a-bezier-path-drawn-in-drawrect-swift.

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh:The above circle on that image  i have shown is a static one.I need this to have a circular animation.For ex:Rotating  Ceiling Fan kind of.

Answer (score 1):

What you got looks completely overcomplicated in the first place. Take a look at the following example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    class RainbowView: UIView {

        var segmentCount: Int = 10 {
            didSet {
                refresh()
            }
        }
        var lineWidth: CGFloat = 10 {
            didSet {
                refresh()
            }
        }

        override var frame: CGRect {
            didSet {
                refresh()
            }
        }

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            refresh()
        }

        private var currentGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?

        private func refresh() {
            currentGradientLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

            guard segmentCount > 0 else { return }

            currentGradientLayer = {
                let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
                gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
                gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
                gradientLayer.type = .conic
                let colors: [UIColor] = {
                    var colors: [UIColor] = [UIColor]()
                    for i in 0..<segmentCount {
                        colors.append(UIColor(hue: CGFloat(i)/CGFloat(segmentCount), saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1))
                    }
                    colors.append(UIColor(hue: 0.0, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)) // Append start color at the end as well to complete the circle
                    return colors;
                }()
                gradientLayer.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }

                gradientLayer.frame = bounds
                layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

                gradientLayer.mask = {
                    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                    shapeLayer.frame = bounds
                    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
                    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: lineWidth*0.5, left: lineWidth*0.5, bottom: lineWidth*0.5, right: lineWidth*0.5))).cgPath
                    return shapeLayer
                }()

                return gradientLayer
            }()


        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview({
            let view = RainbowView(frame: CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 100.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))

            var angle: CGFloat = 0.0
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0/60.0, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                angle += 0.01
                view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
            })

            return view
        }())
    }

}
```

So a view is generated that uses a conical gradient with mask to draw the circle you are describing. Then a transform is applied to the view to rotate it. And a `Timer` is scheduled to rotate the circle.

Note that this code will leak because timer is nowhere invalidated. It needs to be removed when view disappears or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to attach an animation that repeats forever:

```swift
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation") // Create rotation animation
animation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude                // Repeat animation for as long as we can
animation.fromValue = 0                                         // Rotate from 0
animation.toValue = 2 * Float.pi                                //        to 360 deg
animation.duration = 1                                          // During 1 second

self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "animation")                  // Adding the animation to the view
```

`self` - is `RainbowCircle`, assuming that you add this code to one of the methods inside it.

Answer (score 0):

For this we can have Image something like this

[image: Like this Image]

```
syncImage.image = UIImage(named:"spinning")
```

Create a below extension to Start/Stop Rotating

```
extension UIView {
    // To animate
    func startRotating(duration: Double = 1) {
        let kAnimationKey = "rotation"

        if self.layer.animationForKey(kAnimationKey) == nil {
            let animate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
            animate.duration = duration
            animate.repeatCount = Float.infinity            
            animate.fromValue = 0.0
            animate.toValue = Float(M_PI * 2.0)
            self.layer.addAnimation(animate, forKey: kAnimationKey)
        }
    }
    func stopRotating() {
        let kAnimationKey = "rotation"

        if self.layer.animationForKey(kAnimationKey) != nil {
            self.layer.removeAnimationForKey(kAnimationKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
func startSpinning() {
    syncImage.startRotating()
}

func stopSpinning() {
    syncImage.stopRotating()
}

func handleSyncTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    startSpinning()

    let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.stopSpinning()
    })
}
```