# Draw A Path with Animation

Tags: swift, core-animation

I want to draw a path with animation in my application I used the code below but there is no animation and it only adds the result of the path to View even when I make the duration longer than normal.

```swift
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 38.5, y: 88.5))
bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 86.5, y: 88.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 41.5, y: 88.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 86.5, y: 88.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 86.5, y: 64.5))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 145.5, y: 64.5))
UIColor.black.setStroke()
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1
bezierPath.stroke()

layer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
layer.strokeEnd = 0
layer.lineWidth = 1
layer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
layer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

animation.toValue = 1
animation.duration = 20 // seconds
layer.add(animation, forKey: "Line")
self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

I don't know how to make it animate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animate a bezier path drawn in drawRect() Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847408/animate-a-bezier-path-drawn-in-drawrect-swift)

Comment: No, it still doesn't animate ‍♂️

Comment: What is `animation`?

Comment: Oh I updated the question sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my machine, here is the full class, and code :

[https://github.com/Shah3r/testAnim](https://github.com/Shaarshin/testAnim)

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Use CATransaction
    CATransaction.begin()

    //Set Layer
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.lineWidth = 3
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    //Set Bezier Path
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 38.5, y: 88.5))
    bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 86.5, y: 88.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 41.5, y: 88.5), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 86.5, y: 88.5))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 86.5, y: 64.5))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 145.5, y: 64.5))

    //Set Animation
     let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0.0
    animation.toValue = 1
    animation.duration = 7.0 // seconds

  //Completion Block
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{
        print("Animation completed")
    }

    //Add path and animation
    layer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    layer.add(animation, forKey: "Line")
    CATransaction.commit()

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
 }
}
```

Comment: it just appears on view without any animation

Comment: Did you try in an empty Xcode project ? or wanna share the rest of the code to see what's not working ?

Comment: i'm trying this on empty project but this doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206532/discussion-between-shaher-kassam-and-alireza12t).